# Parallel.ForEach return order by input not by execution into list/dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, plinq, concurrentdictionary

If you have this:

```
var resultlist = new List<Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();
Parallel.ForEach(input, item =>
{
    resultlist.Add(SomeDataDictionary(item));
});
```

The return data will be in the order in which the method `SomeDataDictionary` returns the data and will not be in the order of the input.

Is there a way to keep the order of input?

Or is the only way to change the datatype and use a `Parallel.For` loop and then pass the index to some type of array return type?

Comment: When you put it in parallel you do not know in what order they operations are going to complete. If the input is indexed in some way, you can sort the collection once it is done

Comment: You can even use a `SortedSet<T>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List<T>` is not *thread safe*, that's why `resultlist.Add` is *incorrect* in the context. I suggest using *PLinq* instead:

```
 var resultlist = input
   .AsParallel()
   // .AsOrdered() // uncomment this if you want to preserve input order 
   .Select(item => SomeDataDictionary(item))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. what is the performance of plinq vs parallel.foreach. Do you know please?

Comment: @nik: `Parallel.ForEach` is comparable with `.AsParallel()`. The main difficulty is that `List<T>` is *not thread safe*, so either you have to add *lock* within `Parallel.ForEach` (which drops the performace) or let *PLinq* do the entire work for you in the best way.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution using *ConcurrentDictionary*

You can use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) because it is thread-safe and you can use the `Key` to store the order.

```
var resultDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<double, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();

// Use For-Loop index as Key
Parallel.ForEach(input, (item, state, index) => {
    resultDictionary.TryAdd(index, SomeDataDictionary(item));
});

// Convert the dictionary to a list in the required order
var resultList = resultDictionary.Keys.OrderBy(k => k).Select(k => resultDictionary[k]).ToList();
```

### *ConcurrentDictionary* vs *PLinq* performance

Dmitry Bychenko provides a valid PLinq solution in a separate answer.

Let's build a test harness to compare the solutions:

```
class so42112722
{
    private readonly int[] input = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000).ToArray();

    public so42112722()
    {

    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        var t1 = timeAction(ParallelUsingLoopStateAndDictionary);
        var t2 = timeAction(ParallelUsingPLinq);

        var diff = (t1 - t2);
        var pct = diff / (t1 > t2 ? t2 : t1);

        Console.WriteLine("| {0:0,000.000} | {1:0,000.000} | {2} is {3:0.00%} faster!", t1, t2, (diff > 0 ? "PLinq" : "ConcurrentDictionary"), Math.Abs(pct));
    }


    double timeAction(Action action)
    {
        var name = action.Method.Name;

        var tStart = DateTime.Now;

        action();

        var tEnd = DateTime.Now;
        var duration = (tEnd - tStart).TotalMilliseconds;

        return duration;
    }

    private void ParallelUsingLoopStateAndDictionary()
    {
        var resultDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<double, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>();

        Parallel.ForEach(input, (item, state, index) =>
        {
            resultDictionary.TryAdd(index, ExpensiveTransformation(item));
        });

        var resultList = resultDictionary.Keys.OrderBy(k => k).Select(k => resultDictionary[k]).ToList();

    }

    private void ParallelUsingPLinq()
    {
        var reultslist = input
            .AsParallel()
            .AsOrdered()
            .Select(item => ExpensiveTransformation(item))
            .ToList();
    }

    private Dictionary<DateTime, double> ExpensiveTransformation(double item)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int iterCount = 5000;

        var dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i * 3).AddMinutes(i).AddSeconds(item * rnd.Next(100, 1000)).AddMilliseconds(-i);

            var val = Math.Pow(item, rnd.Next(2, 5)) + rnd.Next(100, iterCount) / (i + 1);

            dict.Add(dt, val);
        }

        return dict;
    }

}
```

Now we can execute the test using a simple Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    so42112722 test = new so42112722();

    Console.WriteLine("Comparing ConcurrentDictionary to PLinq:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test.RunTest();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Comparing ConcurrentDictionary to PLinq:
| 7,310.756 | 7,597.217 | ConcurrentDictionary is 3.92% faster!
| 7,883.528 | 7,978.108 | ConcurrentDictionary is 1.20% faster!
| 8,075.709 | 8,072.501 | PLinq is 0.04% faster!
| 8,206.721 | 8,193.054 | PLinq is 0.17% faster!
| 8,256.499 | 8,305.187 | ConcurrentDictionary is 0.59% faster!
| 8,424.029 | 8,286.195 | PLinq is 1.66% faster!
| 8,316.973 | 8,261.499 | PLinq is 0.67% faster!
| 8,312.165 | 8,254.285 | PLinq is 0.70% faster!
| 8,328.433 | 8,369.385 | ConcurrentDictionary is 0.49% faster!
| 8,472.054 | 8,344.197 | PLinq is 1.53% faster!
```

(Figures are in milliseconds.)

This test was executed on a quad-core Intel Core i5 CPU. Your mileage may vary.

PLinq was faster 6 times out of 10, but the difference is minute. And overall, based on 10 test iterations, `ConcurrentDictionary` method came out faster by a whopping 74.76 milliseconds (0.092%). Looks a lot like the [United States presidential election, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2016), where you can get more votes and still lose :).

### Verdict

Don't try to over-optimise your code. The .Net Framework is here to help you. If PLinq will simplify your code - use it; on the other hand, if you need more control - take it.

Comment: rThe performance test just show both are equal. The seen differences are just noise from your system and GC :o) (you can compare ConcurrentDictionary vs. ConcurrentDictionary and you will get the same results => ConcurrentDictionary wins over the same ConcurrentDictionary)